# How To make an jQuery sort for 2 colums

Tags: jquery, html

i need to make a sort on a table 
We have table columns Manager , referral name , referral age
and the possibility to sort Manager and after this the manager sort the referral name on each manager

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://crm.studenttravel.us/js/sort.js"></script>
<table class="sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Manager</th> 
     <th>name</th>
     <th>age</th>
  </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Alex manager</td> 
     <td>Victor</td>
     <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Alex manager</td> 
     <td>Alber</td>
     <td>26</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Alex manager</td> 
     <td>Jessica</td>
     <td>46</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Fred manager</td> 
     <td>Alisa</td>
     <td>16</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Fred manager</td> 
     <td>Dan</td>
     <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see your jQuery code anywhere. That may be *main* reason why it's not working

Comment: Sorry, SO is not place for `write code for me to copy-paste`. Try something first, and only than post here

Comment: Sorry i added the js and i don't now how to make it tho sort